# Delphi BDE Issue $2501

Tags: delphi, bde

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BDE initialization failure (error $2501) on Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866485/bde-initialization-failure-error-2501-on-vista)

These days our client keep encountering the BDE issue with error code $2501 when trying to open two instances of application share the same alias

> An error occurred while attempting to initialize the Borland Database Engine (error $2501)

But if close one of them, or just open one instance, the issue's gone.

And I've try to configure the SHAREMEMSIZE & SHAREMEMLOCATION, but with no luck the issue still there.

Any idea to get around it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866485/bde-initialization-failure-error-2501-on-vista  Looks like a duplicate of that

Comment: Thanks for your remind, @Heffernan, I've read that post, but they are not the same question, my application works fine under XP, W2k, Vista or even Windows 7, but it failed only when two or more instances are running at the same time

Comment: @todofixthis, can you help to re-open this question? It's not the same with that post you listed

Comment: Edit your question to indicate how your issue is different and then flag it so that a moderator can re-open it.

Answer (score 7):

Our Paradox/BDE-based software is running on have several thousand networked, five or so users/installation in different cities and companies

We've seen the dreaded $2501 error on several dozen of them over the past few years.

SHAREDMEMSIZE=4096 and SHAREDMEMLOCATION=0x5BDE have always worked for us to get past this error.

So, take heart! The BDE is *still* alive, even more than a decade since it was last updated.

Should we all move on to a more modern platform? YES!

Are many of us frustrated by the shortcomings of its LocalSQL, etc.? YES!

Are many of us impressed that it still works at all?  YES!

Are many of us stuck maintaining legacy code that would be too expensive to migrate to a new database? YES!   (heavy sigh)

Comment: Presumably you mean SHAREMEMSIZE=4096 and
SHAREMEMLOCATION=0x5BDE

Comment: Thanks, @DavidHeffernan.  I had the word "respectively" but added the IDs just now. Makes it more clear.

Comment: Thanks, @Frank, actually I've try that magic number 4096 & 0x5BDE, but it just works for a while, the issue still happen after that

Comment: Hi, @Leo.W, sorry that I don't have any other suggestions for you.